# How to use backbone.js model and views

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I have a user table in which I have some field e.g. name, email, image etc.

I can load many user at a time, eg. if there is a view for user

```
<div>username
<img of user >
<email>
<user message>
</div>
```

So when I fetch the data of user from db and create the backbone.js model and create the different view from the user data like in profile edit, in small view, big view, and if i change a data of user, it should change in all views.

Actually I would like to see a similar example, or a way to know how it can be implemented.

Comment: I don't really see a question asked at all. Could you be a little more precise in what you're having problems with? Are you just needing links to backbone.js tutorials or getting started?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the official [example application](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/examples/todos/index.html). Play with their GUI.

Then read the [annotated source](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/docs/todos.html). Then read it again.

You should now have an good idea about how to use backbone.

Comment: Then try [some](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/getting-started-with-backbone-js/) [of](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-apps-spinejs/#more-3311) [these](http://addyosmani.com/blog/building-spas-jquerys-best-friends/)